# free jqgrid: keep horizontal scroll in autoresize mode

Tags: scrollbar, free-jqgrid

Is it a possible to keep grid's horizontal scrollbar (not a window scroll) called by

```
autowidth: true,
shrinkToFit: false,
```

After column resized

```
cmTemplate: { compact: true, autoResizable: true },
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc9tkygv/7/).

Steps:
Move left border of result window to right to get grid's scrool (see [pix1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ADG.png)), then
double click the column border line - scroll bar become a lost.
My real table is too wide, so I need to save grid's scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Has found an answer by using the following option

```
autoResizing: { adjustGridWidth: false},
```

Comment: I see another issue for me in same jsfiddle. The `autoresizeOnLoad: true` option doesn't resize column as expected